# How to make a controlled discharge of batteries connected to the grid?

Tags: solar-power, wind-power, batteries

I currently have 1600 W wind turbine with grid tie inverters of 12-24 volt 1600 W and I now want to add batteries to my system with a controlled discharge, Adjustable from 10-20 amps without disconnecting the net from the grid. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This question probably belongs over on electronics.SE, but I imagine it's too late to migrate at this point - voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Electronics.SE, but is too old to migrate.